# If you are immune to shakened, are you immune to the whole fear chain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, fear

I was reading the rage powers of the barbarian and [fearless rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/fearless-rage-ex) says you are immune to shaken and frightened. Since shaken < frightened < panicked, if you cant be shaken does that prevent the worse conditions as well?

Answer (score 3):

No, being immune to Shaken gives you the wherewithal to ignore things that would normally be intimidating or downright scary to you, but not the ability to shrug of things that are truly horrifying.

You would not be vulnerable to enemies stacking various Fear effects on you, but if something makes you outright Panicked, you still Panic as per the condition.

The ability doesn't say you have immunity to Panicked, so you don't.

For reference, I don't consider greater Conditions to be "secondary effects" of lesser Conditions.

> Immunity (Ex or Su)
>
> A creature with immunities takes no damage from listed sources. Immunities can also apply to afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and other effects. A creature that is immune does not suffer from these effects, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "secondary effects" are things like http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/frightful-aspect/ "Each time a creature shaken by this aura hits you with a melee attack, that creature becomes frightened for 1d4 rounds". Creatures with immunity to the Shaken condition would therefore also be immune to this particular path to becoming Frightened.

Comment: @minnmass: yes but that's only because the creature would not be "a creature shaken by this aura", which you need to be to trigger the effect.

Comment: Well that and you're also immune to Frightened anyway... only things that cause Panicked directly work, such as the 4th(ish) level spell [Fear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fear/)